# Prove that $e^x>x+1 \forall x\ne 0$

Tags: functional-inequalities

I need to prove that $e^x>x+1 \forall x\ne 0$.

Any ideas of hints about how to begin? I don't have any idea except the graphical way.

Comment: Have you heard about the mean value theorem?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714172/proof-that-e-x-ge-1-x/1714216#1714216 I point you to my answer to this question.

Comment: Do you know taylor series expansion of $e^x$?

Comment: Proved that using derivates by myself,the same as this http://math.stackexchange.com/a/504668/390996

Answer (score 2):

By the Bernoulli inequality,
$$1+x\leq \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$
 and
$$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n\rightarrow e^x.$$

An interesting way to prove strictness is also by Bernoulli,
If $$a^x=x+1$$
then 
$$1+x(a-1)\leq a^x=1+x$$
and thus $a\leq 2$. $e$ however is $>2$.

In fact $\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ is increasing for all $x$. And the first term in the sequence is $1+x$. The strict inequality for all $x$ then follows from $1+x<\left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)^2$ for all $x\neq 0$.

Comment: This does not show strict inequality for $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\frac{d}{dx} (e^x-x-1)=e^x-1.$$

Then try to study the variations of $x\mapsto e^x-x-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$g(t)=\ln(t+1)-t$$

for $t\geq0$.

$$\forall t>0\;\; g'(t)=-\frac{t}{1+t}<0$$

$$\implies \forall t>0\;\; \;\ln(t+1)-t<g(0)=0$$

$$\implies \forall t>0\;\;\; t+1<e^t$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{e^x}{x+1}>1$$
$$1+\frac{\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+....}{x+1}>1$$