# Show that $\left(kx-1\right)e^{kx}>-1$ holds $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}^*, \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^*$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

How to show that:

$\forall k\in\mathbb{N}^*$ and $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^*$, the inequality $\left(kx-1\right)e^{kx}>-1$ holds.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's just $e^y>1+y$ for $y=-kx$.

Comment: Alright :D, thanks.

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252541/prove-that-ex-ge-x1-for-all-real-x

Comment: Yes it's with Bernoulli then... Thank you for your help @yurnero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We consider the function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=(kx-1)e^{kx}$ with $k$ a natural integer (excluding zero).

Let $X=kx$. We then have $f(X)=(X-1)e^X$. Let's show that $f$ is strictly superior to $-1$.

$f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ where:
\begin{align*}
\forall X\in\mathbb{R},\ f'(X)&=\left((X-1)e^X\right)'\\
&=Xe^X
\end{align*}
Knowing that $e^X>0$ on $\mathbb{R}$, then $f'$ is of the sign of $X$. $f$ is strictly decreasing for $X<0$ and strictly increasing for $X>0$. Hence, the function has a minimum at $X=0$ which equals:
\begin{align*}
f(0)&=(0-1)e^0\\
&=-1
\end{align*}
Thus, if we exclude X=0, we have *a fortiori*, $f(X)>f(0)\Leftrightarrow f(x)>-1\Leftrightarrow (kx-1)e^{kx}>-1$.

Answer (score 2):

It results from the variations of $f$ on $\mathbf R$: $f'(x)=k^2x\mathrm e^{kx}$, so $f$  decreases on $\mathbf R^-$,  increases on $\mathbf R^+$  and has a minimum at $x=0$, hence for $x\ne 0$, $f(x)>f(0)=-1$.

Comment: I think $x=0$ or $k=0$ is ruled out by the specification of the problem.

Comment: Oh! I misread as $x\in \mathbf R$. I'll fix it.