# How to prove that $er^2 \leq e^{r^2}$ for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization

I'm trying to prove the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $$f(x,y)=(x^2+y^2)e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$$ attains a maximum at every point of the unit circle. The determinant of the hessian matrix at those points is zero so I wrote $f$ in polar coordinates and tryed to prove there is no $r \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $$r^2e^{-r^2}>e^{-1}$$ which is equivalent to $$e^{r^2}<er^2$$ I don't know how to prove it, any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Your statement is false for $0\leq r<1$ (and you don't need to consider $r<0$ since the domain is restricted due to the coordinate transformation).

Comment: Recall: [$e^z\geq 1+z$ for $z\in\mathbb{R}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252541/prove-that-ex-ge-x1-for-all-real-x). Use this with $z=r^2-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be proven more easily. Consider $$f(z) = z e^{-z} (z\geq 0) \quad f'(z) = (1-z)e^{-z}$$
The derivative is $0$ only for $z=1$. Since $f'(z) > 0 $ for $z<1$ and $f'(z) < 0$ for $z>1$, $z=1$ corresponds to a unique maximum.

Comment: Of course, didn't realize I had to think it as a one variable extrema problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The function $g(r) = e^r$ is strictly convex, therefore its graph lies
above each tangent line:
$$
 e^r = g(r) \ge g(1) + g'(1)(r-1) = er
$$
with equality only for $r=1$.